# What is this ring called?

Tags: number-theory

While thinking about my other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3464491/is-this-contrived-sequence-eventually-periodic) I found that it  would be easier to talk about it if numbers just weren't so finite. There is a notion mentioned there in the [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3464491/is-this-contrived-sequence-eventually-periodic#comment7128153_3466411) of "list of congruences, possible or impossible" and I'm wondering if this idea has a more concise name.

So let's define a set $R$. Elements of $R$ are sequences $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots$ such that $\forall i. 0 \le a_i < i$ and for every finite $k$ the system
$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
n\equiv a_1\pmod 1 \\
n\equiv a_2\pmod 2 \\
\vdots\\
n\equiv a_k\pmod k \\
\end{array}
\right. $$
has a solution in n.

One can define the ring operations in a straightforward way, and there is an obvious injective ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to R$.

$R$ is uncountable, $R$ is compact as a subspace of Baire space $\mathbb{N^N}$.

My question is what $R$ and its elements are called.

Comment: This is something like the adele ring of the rationals. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adele_ring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the elements are called [profinite integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_integer) and the ring is called profinite completion of the integers.

Thanks to Gerry Myerson for the lead.